# Write content of column into a long string

Tags: r

I have a data frame of song lyrics from Christmas songs. It looks approx. like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(line = c("I don't want a lot for Christmas", 
                           "There is just one thing I need", 
                           "I don't care about the presents", 
                           "Underneath the Christmas tree", 
                           "I just want you for my own"))
```

I want to get this ready for sentiment analysis. In order to do that, I need this to be one long string. So:

```
"I don't want a lot for Christmas There is just one thing I need I don't care about the presents Underneath the Christmas tree I just want you for my own"
```

Punctuation and everything is entirely irrelevant for my purposes, I just need the above output stored as a string. How can I save this data frame column as one long string?

Comment: `paste(df1$line, collapse = " ")`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(line = c("I don't want a lot for Christmas", 
                           "There is just one thing I need", 
                           "I don't care about the presents", 
                           "Underneath the Christmas tree", 
                           "I just want you for my own"))

string <- df1$line

string %>% 
  #Remove punctuation
  iconv(., from = "UTF-8", to = 'ASCII//TRANSLIT') %>% 
  #Collapse into a single string, using space as a separator
  str_c(.,collapse = " ")

[1] "I don't want a lot for Christmas There is just one thing I need I don't care about the presents Underneath the Christmas tree I just want you for my own"
```